# django-fluent-comments model doesn't appear in Wagtail ModelAdmin

Tags: django, wagtail, django-comments

I have a Wagtail project that uses [django-fluent-comments](https://github.com/django-fluent/django-fluent-comments%22django-fluent-comments) and I would like to be able moderate the comments in the admin pages. Based on [this tutorial](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5/reference/contrib/modeladmin.html) I added this to my `wagtail_hooks.py` file:

```
class CommentAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = FluentComment

    menu_label = 'Comments'
    menu_icon = 'list-ul'
    menu_order = 200
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    list_display = ('user', 'comment')

modeladmin_register(CommentAdmin)
```

But when I go to the Admin pages, there is no comments tab and no errors shown. I have tried to add a Pages model to my Admin page and that worked fine.

The `FluentComment` model is just:

```
class FluentComment(Comment):
    """
    Proxy model to make sure that a ``select_related()`` is performed on the ``user`` field.
    """
    objects = FluentCommentManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

(In [this file](https://github.com/django-fluent/django-fluent-comments/blob/master/fluent_comments/models.py)) So I wonder if I have the correct model. But the if I add `print model.objects.all()` to my `CommentAdmin` class it shows all my comments in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `FluentComment` to `django_comments.models.Comment`. `FluentComment` is [Proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) which wagtail's modeladmin does not like.

Comment: Thanks so much! I wondered if the Proxy model was the problem but had no idea what to do about it.